# With Flask and JQuery, how to delete a record by "POST" method in "sexy" way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am using Flask to make a small web app. I need to implement CRUD operation in this app. My main problem is how to implement the "Delete" operation in a proper and "sexy" way. I can implement "Delete" operation with "GET" method originally. But after reading a bunch of documents, I found this is not a good way for sure.

So I tried some solutions to implement "Delete" operation with "POST" method and finally I am using the following code:

**HTML**

```
{% block mainbody %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>{{ _('User Setting') }}</h3>
    </div>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><label>{{ _('Article Category') }}</label></legend>
        <table class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <tbody>
                {% for article_category in article_categories %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ article_category.name }}</td>
                    <td width="30px"><a href="{{ url_for('user.edit_article_category', id=article_category.id) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
                    <td width="30px"><a href="#" data-record-url="{{ url_for('user.delete_article_category', id=article_category.id) }}" data-record-title="{{ article_category.name }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ url_for('user.add_article_category') }}" class="btn" style="margin-top:10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> {{ _('Create New Article Category') }}</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ _('Confirm Delete') }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ _('You are about to delete this record:') }} <strong><span id="deleted-content"></span></strong>, {{ _('the procedure is irreversible') }}.</p>
                <p>{{ _('Do you want to proceed?') }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{{ _('Cancel') }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">{{ _('Delete') }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
                }
            }
        });
        $('#confirm-delete-modal').on('click', '.btn-ok', function(e) {
            var recordUrl = $(this).data('recordUrl');
            $.post(recordUrl, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            $('#confirm-delete-modal').modal('hide');
        });
        $('#confirm-delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var recordTitle = $(e.relatedTarget).data('recordTitle');
            var recordUrl = $(e.relatedTarget).data('recordUrl');
            $(e.currentTarget).find('#deleted-content').text(recordTitle);
            $(e.currentTarget).find('.btn-ok').data('recordUrl', recordUrl);
        });
        $('#confirm-delete-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
            location.reload(false);
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Flask**

```
@user.route("/setting/article-category/<int:id>/delete", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def delete_article_category(id):
    deleting_article_category = ArticleCategory.get(ArticleCategory.id == id)
    deleting_article_category.delete_instance()
    return redirect(url_for("user.setting"))
```

The above code does work, but there are at least two drawbacks.

1. `/user/setting (url_for("user.setting"))` page content is transferred twice. The first time is what the Flask code `return redirect(url_for("user.setting"))` makes. The second time is what the JQuery code `location.reload(false)` makes. It seems that the two code segments are repeat. But I cannot delete any of them. If I delete JQuery code, the `/user/setting (url_for("user.setting"))` page cannot get auto-refresh after I confirmed the modal and really deleted the record from the DB, which means the deleted item looks still staying there until I refresh the page manually. This is certainly inconsistent result I should avoid. If I delete Flask code `return redirect(url_for("user.setting"))` or change it to `return Null`, I will receive a 500 error from server. Although the record still can be deleted in fact, I can catch this error from the Javascript Console of Chrome. I cannot suffer this.
2. The JQuery code `location.reload(false)` will download a lot of supporting stuff like bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js, logo.png, rather than the pure html file. Even I have used the `false` parameter to ask it try to find those stuff from the browser's cache.

Because of the above two drawbacks, I think my code's efficiency is too low. Who can help me to improve my code?

By using `console.log(data)`, I noticed that the Flask code `return redirect(url_for("user.setting"))` has already caused JQuery's `$.post()` operation get the new page content in the feedback data. The new page content is pretty correct, which means the deleted record is not listed there any more. But  there is no page refresh mechanism which can use this correct data. I think this is the key leading the low efficiency.

I am thinking Flask should provide some easy method to safely delete DB record. Just a deleting operation, which is much more complex than editing or adding. Is it because I don't know how to use Form to implement it or there is other reason to make deleting operation too hard? I am a beginner so maybe my thinking is wrong.

Is there some advice to me? Thanks!

Update for packet capture tool - `Charles` screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Ahaha that killed me

Comment: My "sexy" means full of function but without any extra code and data flow. (slim body without any extra fat :))

Comment: Why not use a HTTP DELETE method?

Comment: @leovp It seems that "DELETE" method is used for RESTful API and browser can only support "GET" and "POST" method. I am developing the app for browser now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to send full page in return to DELETE request. Empty [HTTP 204](https://httpstatuses.com/204) response is the standard return value for such request:

```
def delete_article_category(id):
    deleting_article_category = ArticleCategory.get(ArticleCategory.id == id)
    deleting_article_category.delete_instance()
    return Response(status=204)
```

You don't need to worry about refreshing page as all static files are got by browser from its cache. Unless you use `location.reload(true)`, of course. Check the logs of your application: most probably it serves static files with HTTP 304 code (Not Modified) like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2017 10:10:10] "GET /static/admin/bootstrap/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=3.3.5 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: I verified your answer. Your solution `return Response(status=204)` does solve my re-transfer data issue. Thanks a lot! While I am still not very clear about the static file re-transfer fact. Although HTTP 304 code indicates there is no modification for the request data, it seems that the server still transferred the data as packet capture tool - `Charles` monitored. Is it just "looks like" but without real transfer or I have no way to avoid so I need to just omit it?

Comment: @urbainy Am I correct that your server sends 304 responses for static and with content? It's rather strange: 304 response cannot contain message-body. Perhaps your capture tool shows the contents it has previously received. I have the same behaviour in Firefox development tools: packets with static are shown as "cached" but I still can view their contents.

Comment: The server does show a lot of 304 messages as you said. While `Charles` shows the packets are really send and received with statistics of timestamp,  duration and packet size. I will try to paste a screen-shot in my original post for your check.

Comment: I think you are 100% correct after I check `Charles` packet detail window. There is no message-body. The size showed in the screen-shot should only indicate the header and the necessary payload which does not include the static file. I checked the logo.png which size is 32K while `Charles` only show 997 bytes. So you are right. Thank you again!

Comment: @urbainy I was just going to post about file sizes :) I checked reloading pages on SO: its 304 responses were about 0.5 KB in size. So your 304 responses look correct with their 1 KB. Just maybe too many headers :)